# data-encrypted-name does't work in Code igniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, braintree

I have form input like this

`<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number">`

That's my part of form for entering card number.

That's work just fine when form is not inside codeigniter.

When I put same files on other subdomain with out codeigniter, it works. When in code igniter I set name instead of `data-encrypted-name` it works.

Then I can see `$_POST['number']`, but that's bad douse card number is not encrypted. Between, I'm using Braintree as a payment system.

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you place in index.php(the main index php of codeigniter) var_dump($_POST['number'])? as the first line before codeigniter initialises?
That way you can be sure that codeigniter hasn't done anything with it and that it "arrives" clean.

If then after that the post is readable it means codeigniter handles the decryption for you.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets i'm not sure what you want to say, and what i need to do :/

Comment: The only problem i have is when i put in input name="card", it works(but does not make sense couse it's not encrypted, so i can't , but when i set data-encrypted-name does't work.)

Comment: I'd suggest you use ssl. That's the only secure way. You can get an ssl certificate for as cheap as $7.... or some hosts even cheaper.

Comment: @user3446403 I work at Braintree. You haven't told us what specifically is happening when you try and use `data-encrypted-name` with Codeigniter -- how is it failing? Your best bet is probably to [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) and provide them with more details.

Comment: @agf
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: number

Filename: controllers/main.php

and other posts are good, cause i have other values from that form with name="x" attributes, i get them with $_POST, only value i don't get is $_POST['number'] cause hi is  data-encrypted-name="number"

Comment: @user3446403 The way `braintree.js` works is by taking that field and encrypting it, then adding the `name` attribute based on what is in the `data-encrypted-name` attribute. If you're not seeing the field with the `name` attribute set server-side, then something is interfering with `braintree.js`.

Comment: @agf But i'm using same braintree.js outside code igniter(on same server ofc, and it's working just fine. That's why i don't understood where error is...

Comment: @user3446403 I can't really help any more since you didn't post your code. If you send it to Braintree's support team, they'll be glad to take a look.